# Lost user's rights to access Office Impress (but not Office Writer and co)

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice, shortcuts

Recently (2-3 weeks ago), a message started showing up after clicking on the Impress shortcut. Message is the following (tr. from French): "Object cannot be accessed because user's rights aren't sufficient". But I can still open my already existing .odp files with Impress, modify and save them. I just cannot create a new one from the shortcut. Other Office softwares are starting without troubles from the shortcuts. 
So it doesn't stop me from using the software but it would be easier if I could use the shortcut again. 
Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I've also a windows partition mounted on my computer.

2nd Edit: Even when logged as root (which has got the permission on libreoffice impress) with the `sudo su` command, I cannot open the application directly.

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: From a terminal does `libreoffice --impress` result in the same error?

Comment: If you demount the windows partition do you still get the error?

Comment: @guillermochamorro: I get the same error with the terminal.

Comment: @Graham I'm not really skillfull at mounting/demonting (I did it with a much more skillfull friend) so I can try but I would prefere to explore other options first (if there are!)